# .top jQuery issue with null .top

Tags: jquery

Getting a .top undefined or null error in ie9 for the following code:

```
jQuery('#menu').menu();
jQuery('#menu').find('a').click(function(e){
    if(jQuery(window).width() < 767) {
        jQuery('#menu').toggleClass('show');
    }
    var $go_to = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var param = $go_to.split('#')[1];
    var $go_to_url = $go_to.split('#')[0];
    var $current_url = window.location.href.split('#')[0];      
    var scroll_distance = jQuery('#'+param).offset().top;
    function cleanURL(url) {
            if(url.match(/http:\/\//))
            {
                url = url.substring(7);
            }
            if(url.match(/^www\./))
            {
                url = url.substring(4);
            }

            return url;
    }
    $go_to = cleanURL($go_to_url);
    $current_url = cleanURL($current_url);
    if(jQuery(this).closest('#menu').hasClass('render')) {
        if(param) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if(jQuery('#'+param).length > 0) {

                if(jQuery(window).width() > 767){
                    if(jQuery('.header').hasClass('sticky')){
                        scroll_distance = scroll_distance - jQuery('.header').outerHeight(); 
                    } else {
                        scroll_distance = scroll_distance; 
                    }
                }

                if($go_to == $current_url) { 

                    jQuery('html, body, document').stop().animate({scrollTop: scroll_distance }, 1000, 'easeOutQuart', function(){
                        window.location.hash = param;
                        jQuery('html, body, document').stop().animate({scrollTop: scroll_distance }, 0);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    window.location = $go_to_url+'#'+param;
                }
            } else {
                window.location = $go_to_url+'#'+param;
            }
        } else {
            window.location = $go_to_url;
        }
    }
});
```

Please help!  Basically, the menu should be able to click down to the proper section on a "one page" site.  But there are also sub pages for single blog posts.  On those single blog post pages, when the menu items are clicked, the error is thrown.  My belief is that it has something to do with there not being a param on the sub pages (nor a blank param) but rather a sub page url.  THoughts?

Comment: `console.log(jQuery('#'+param).length)`

Comment: IF the code posted by Kevin B === 0, then `offset()` is undefined. Basically make sure your param is valid.

Comment: There is such a thing as `location.hash` built in ?

Comment: I added that to my js file, and it didn't log anything at all.  Just to give some context, I am working on customization of this theme: http://prothemeus.com/demo/bravo/. If you click on a single blog page, and then click a navigation item, it will throw the error on click in modern browsers, but pop up in ie9.

Comment: Ah. I had the above code in the wrong place.  Moved it and it now logs as "1."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest replacing this line:

`var scroll_distance = jQuery('#'+param).offset().top;`

With something like this:

`var scroll_distance = jQuery('#'+param).length ? jQuery('#'+param).offset().top : 0;`

If `jQuery('#'+param)` returns no object, then `.offset()` is undefined.

This way you can then test if `scroll_distance` was defined and only attempt your other actions when it is:

```
if (scroll_distance) {  
  //your logic goes here
}
```